# Alter Table add column and check constraint in one script - getting Invalid column name on constraint

Tags: sql-server

I'm wanting to run this script as part of another bigger script.

I'm not wanting to add GO statements as the defined variables do not carry past the GO.

As individual statements they work, but when run as a whole, I get error:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'ECLIPSECapable'.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Providers]
ADD [ECLIPSECapable] [char](1) NULL;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Providers]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [ICProvidersECLIPSECapable] CHECK  (([ECLIPSECapable]='N' OR [ECLIPSECapable]='Y'))

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Providers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [ICProvidersECLIPSECapable]
```

Comment: I guess the reason for not working is that you'd need to 'commit' the DDL change before that column is seen. Normally you would not want to mix DDL and DML changes in the same script anyway...

Comment: Add "GO" between each statement to commit the batch statement.
That said, personally I would have gone for a bit field, not null, default 0... then no need for the check constraint.

Comment: I can add the constraint in a separate script .. i.e. have two scripts .. one that adds the column and one that adds the constraint. I will do that ..  I can't add a GO in this case as this upsets other aspects of the script that I have to use. Thankyou for your comments !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just do this in one statement so there is no need to reference the column at all outside the statement that adds it.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Providers]
ADD [ECLIPSECapable] [char](1) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [ICProvidersECLIPSECapable] CHECK  (([ECLIPSECapable]='N' OR [ECLIPSECapable]='Y'))
```

The rest of the code isn't needed ["WITH CHECK is assumed for new constraints"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) anyway so after running that statement you end up with a check constraint that is both enabled and trusted to assure that all data in the table matches the constraint.

In theory SQL Server should be able to skip doing any examination of the rows at all as the statement ensures that all existing rows will have a value of `NULL` for `ECLIPSECapable`, and this is a metadata only change, and it is possible to determine that this constant value doesn't violate the check constraint up front - but I'm not sure if SQL Server implements this optimisation.

Comment: This won't work if you need to update the new column value before adding the constraint because existing rows would violate it.

Comment: @TimScott - that is not the scenario the questioner here is asking about, so not sure why you are adding a comment that it doesn't work in some other different situation. Here they are adding a column with a value of `NULL`. This passes the check constraint they are trying to add (as only values of `false` fail it rather than `unknown`) and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

Use dynamic SQL break the script into multiple batches:

```
exec ('
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Providers]
ADD [ECLIPSECapable] [char](1) NULL;
');

exec ('
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Providers]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [ICProvidersECLIPSECapable] CHECK  (([ECLIPSECapable]=''N'' OR [ECLIPSECapable]=''Y''))
');

exec ('
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Providers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [ICProvidersECLIPSECapable]
');
```

Comment: Thanks David ... This certainly works as an script in SSMS.

Comment: The script segment I'm adding is wrapped in     BEGIN TRAN         BEGIN TRY     and after script segment is            COMMIT TRAN and     END TRY    followed by     BEGIN CATCH    ROLLBACK TRAN   ...         Am not sure the exec batch answer would honour all this other script logic ..        I think all this logic it to prevent partial script running if script errors are present ..  no matter .. I will mark your answer as correct ..  for my case having 2 separate scripts might be the answer.

Comment: Dynamic SQL will run in the transaction you orchestrate at an outer scope.

Comment: Ah - OK - Thanks for this comment David !

Comment: There isn't any need for multiple batches here. The final `ALTER TABLE ... CHECK` is redundant and the rest can be done in one statement